# Using sfFilter to update DB with Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, filter, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I've created a sfFilter to update the current module where the user is at:

```
class SessionFilter extends sfFilter {
    public function execute($filterChain){
        if ($this->isFirstCall()){
            $user = $this->getContext()->getUser()->getId();
            $module = $this->getContext()->getModuleName();
            Doctrine::getTable('ActiveSession')->set($user, $module);
            Doctrine::getTable('ActiveSession')->refresh();
        }

        $filterChain->execute();
    }
}
```

When I look up into the db I found out that the record has set the field 'module' at 'default' but when I see the log it says:

```
UPDATE active_session SET module = 'secretary' WHERE (sys_user_id = '2')
```

Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour?

EDIT: I forgot to put the set and refresh method's

```
class ActiveSessionTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    public function set($userId, $module){
        $q = $this->createQuery()->update()
            ->set('module','?', $module)
            ->where("sys_user_id = ?", array($userId))->execute();
    }

    public function refresh(){
        $time = time() - sfConfig::get('app_session_keep') * 60;
        $this->createQuery()->delete()->where('time < ?', $time)->execute();
    }
    ...
}
```

The refresh method should be used in other method but for testing I'm keeping it there.

Comment: Why are you using refresh? I guess you must use `save()` method.

Comment: The refresh is a static method that keeps only the users who's been active in the past 10 minutes. I forgot to put the set method.

Comment: It's really strange. Try to activate the query log on mysql, and see what's really happen: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: Thx! I saw the log and found out that the first call is actually doing what i try to do but, don't know why, the query is called by default 1 or 2 times after so that's why i'm getting that result. The other strange thing is that using the symfony log i only found 1 call :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... to close this.

The only way I could accomplish what I wanted was to check if module was 'default':

```
class ActiveSessionTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    public function set($userId, $module){
        if($module != 'default'){
            $q = $this->createQuery()->update()
               ->set('module','?', $module)
               ->where("sys_user_id = ?", array($userId))->execute();
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

really not a happy answer but couldn't find the right one.